# Show that there exists a set $E \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that the cross sections are borel sets, but $E \notin B\otimes B$

Tags: measure-theory, tensor-products, borel-sets

From Axler's MIRA

> Let $B$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that there exists a set $E \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $[E]_a \in B$ and $[E]^a \in B$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, but $E \notin B \otimes B$.

Here $[E]_a$ is the cross section with a fixed second coordinate and $[E]^a$ is the cross section with a fixed first coordinate. Currently my approach to this problem is to use a non-measurable set such as the vitali set $V$ so that $V \times V \notin B \oplus B$ and then having the projection onto an axis make it trivially a Borel subset, however everytime I try to write this up it ends up being wrong so I am wondering if I am even going in the right direction with this problem now.

edit: Here is what I wrote up so far btw
[image]

Comment: Your construction does not work. It is well-known that $V$ is not
Borel measurable (actually, not even Lebesgue measurable). You define
$E=V\times V$. Pick $a\in V$, then the section $E_{a}=\{x\mid(x,a)\in E\}=\{x\mid(x,a)\in V\times V\}=\{x\mid x\in V\mbox{ and }a\in V\}=\{x\mid x\in V\}=V$,
which is not Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Sheldon Axler's hints, we construct $E$ without invoking the Continuum Hypothesis.
Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0,1]$ by $x\sim y$ iff
$x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Denote the quotient set $[0,1]/\sim$ by $\{A_{i}\mid i\in I\}$.
By the Axiom of Choice, there exists a map $\theta:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}=[0,1]$
such that $\theta(i)\in A_{i}$ for each $i$. Denote $V=\theta(I)$.
We go to show that $V$ is not Lebesgue measurable by contradiction.

Suppose the contrary that $V$ is Lebesgue measurable. Let $\mathbb{Q}_{1}=\mathbb{Q}\cap[-1,1]$.
We assert that $[0,1]\subseteq\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)\subseteq[-1,2]$
and the union is disjoint. Denote $x_{i}=\theta(i)$. Let $x\in[0,1]$,
then $x\sim x_{i}$ for some $i$. Clearly $r_{0}:=x-x_{i}\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}$.
Therefore, $x=x_{i}+r_{0}\in V+r_{0}\subseteq\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)$.
Let $x\in\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)$, then $x=x_{i}+r$
for some $i\in I$ and $r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}$. Note that $x_{i}\in[0,1]$
and $r\in[-1,1]$, so $x\in[-1,2]$. Finally, we go to show that the
union $\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)$ is disjoint. Suppose
that there exist $r_{1}\neq r_{2}$ such that $(V+r_{1})\cap(V+r_{2})\ne\emptyset$.
Choose $\xi\in(V+r_{1})\cap(V+r_{2})$. $\xi\in(V+r_{1})$ implies
that $\xi=x_{i}+r_{1}$ for some $i$. $\xi\in(V+r_{2})$ implies
that $\xi=x_{j}+r_{2}$ for some $j$. Hence, $x_{i}+r_{1}=x_{j}+r_{2}\Rightarrow x_{i}-x_{j}=r_{2}-r_{1}\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow x_{i}\sim x_{j}\Rightarrow x_{i}=x_{j}$.
It follows that $r_{1}=r_{2}$, which is a contradiction.

Let $l=m(V)$. Since Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, we
have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & m\left(\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)\right)\\
 & = & \sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}m(V+r)\\
 & = & \sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}m(V)\\
 & = & \begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }l=0\\
\infty, & \mbox{ if }l>0
\end{cases},
\end{eqnarray*}
which is impossible because $1=m\left([0,1]\right)\leq m\left(\cup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}_{1}}\left(V+r\right)\right)\leq m([-1,2])=3$.

Finally, we define $E=\{(x,x)\mid x\in V\}$. For each $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E_{t} & = & \{x\mid(x,t)\in E\}\\
 & = & \begin{cases}
\{t\}, & \mbox{ if }t\in V\\
\emptyset, & \mbox{ if }t\notin V
\end{cases}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $E_{t}$ is Borel. Similarly, we can prove that $E^{t}=\{y\mid(t,y)\in V\}$
is Borel. Next, we go to show that $E\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
Let $\pi_{X}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the canonical
projection onto the first coordinate, i.e., $\pi_{X}(x,y)=x$. Let
$\pi_{Y}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the canonical projection
onto the second coordinate. We recall the universal property of joint
measurability: For any map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$,
$f$ is $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{B}$-measurable iff
$\pi_{X}\circ f$ and $\pi_{Y}\circ f$ are measurable. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$
by $f(t)=(t,t)$. Clearly $\pi_{X}\circ f=\pi_{Y}\circ f=\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$,
where $\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{R}}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $\mbox{id}_{\mathbb{R}}(t)=t$,
which is clearly a Borel function. Therefore, $t\mapsto(t,t)$ is
$\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{B}$-measurable. Finally,
$V=f^{-1}(E)$. Since $V\notin\mathcal{B}$, we must have $E\notin\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Sorry @Danny, but after your first killer answer nothing else is going to impress me!

Comment: Hey Danny thanks for the answer! Although I see what you are arguing, the universal property of joint measurability was never defined in the textbook. Thus I think the explanation to show that $E \notin B \times B$ can be simplified. If we project $E$ to its first (or second) coordinate, then $\pi_X(E) = \pi_Y(E)= V$ which is not measurable and this implies that $\pi_X^{-1}(E) \notin \mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @Evan Kim  What is $\pi_X^{-1}(E)$ ?

Comment: The pre-image of the canonical projection onto the first coordinate

Comment: @Evan Kim Think twice before saying... $E$ is a subset of the domain of $\pi_X$.

Comment: Are you saying that $E$ isn't a subset of the domain of $\pi_x$ in this instance? Or in general $E$ might not be a subset of the domain of $\pi_x$?

Comment: You wrote $\pi_X^{-1}(E)$, which only make sense if $E$ is a subset of the co-domain of the map $\pi_X$. However, $E$ is a subset of the domain but not the co-domain.

Answer (score 2):

We prove by assuming the Continuum Hypothesis. Let $\omega_1=\{\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$ be the first uncountable ordinal. Assume that the Continuum Hypothesis holds, i.e., $\omega_1 = c := 2^\omega$. Choose a bijection $\theta:c\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$ Denote $x_{\alpha}=\theta(\alpha)$,
$\alpha<c$. Define $E=\{(x_{\alpha},x_{\beta})\mid\alpha<\beta<c\}$.
We go to show that all $x$-sections and $y$-sections of $E$ are
Borel. Let $t\in\mathbb{R}$ be fixed, then there exists a unique
$\alpha_{0}<c$ such that $t=x_{\alpha_{0}}$.

Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
E_{t} & = & \{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid(x,t)\in E\}\\
 & = & \{x_{\alpha}\mid\alpha<\alpha_{0}\}
\end{eqnarray*}
which is countable, so $E_{t}$ is a Borel set.

Also,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E^{t} & = & \{y\in\mathbb{R}\mid(t,y)\in E\}\\
 & = & \{x_{\beta}\mid\alpha_{0}<\beta<c\}
\end{eqnarray*}
which is co-countable (i.e., its complement is countable. For, the
complement $(E^{t})^{c}=\{x_{\beta}\mid\beta\leq\alpha_{0}\}$ is
countable), so $E^{t}$ is also a Borel set.

Since the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-finite,
Fubini-Tonelli Theorem is applicable. We prove by contradiction that
$E\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose
the contrary that $E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$
then
$$
\int\left(\int1_{E}(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int\left(\int1_{E}(x,y)dy\right)dx.
$$
For each $y$, $1_{E}(x,y)=1_{E_{y}}(x)$, so $\int1_{E}(x,y)dx=\lambda(E_{y})=0$
because $E_{y}$ is a countable set. Hence, $\int\left(\int1_{E}(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int0dy=0$.
On the other hand, for each $x$, $1_{E}(x,y)=1_{E^{x}}(y)$, so $\int1_{E}(x,y)dy=\lambda(E^{x})=\infty$
because $E^{x}$ is co-countable. It follows that $\int\left(\int1_{E}(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int\infty dx=\infty$.
We arrive a contradiction.

Comment: The Continuum Hypothesis is not needed for this exercise. An easier example can be obtained by selecting an appropriate subset of the diagonal $\{(x, x) : x \in \mathbf{R} \}$. Measure, Integration and Real Analysis is an Open Access book, and thus the electronic version is freely and legally available at http://measure.axler.net/.

Comment: @Sheldon Axler Thank you. I present another proof which does not invoke the Continuum Hypothesis.